# Route mail in postfix to different relays based on subject

Tags: postfix

I am looking to configure postfix to route messages to different relays based on the contents of a subject line.

The desired result would be if a user sent an outbound e-mail with a specific tag say "SECURE:" at the start of the subject line it would forward to one relay (1.1.1.1) but if the tag was not specified the message would be delivered another relay (2.2.2.2).

I have investigated header checks, before and after message filtering, and postfix proxy but I have not been able to pin down how to accomplish changing the mail route based on message contents (which seems like it should be a fairly simple thing to do).

I might expect to involve procmail for this task, but would like some assistance in where to begin. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the manual correctly, you can achieve this using header checks with `FILTER transport:destination`.

From [the header_checks part of the manual](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html):

```
The transport name specifies the first field of a mail delivery agent definition
in master.cf; the syntax of the next-hop destination is described in the manual page
of the corresponding delivery agent.
```

In your case, [this would be](http://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html) `smtp:1.1.1.1`

So the full config:

In main.cf:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
relayhost = 2.2.2.2
```

In header_checks:

```
/^Subject: SECURE:/ FILTER smtp:1.1.1.1
```

I haven't tested this at all.

Comment: I did a cursory test in my lab and this worked great. I did have to change the regex pattern to `/^SECURE:/ FILTER smtp:1.1.1.1`. Much better than my iptables suggestion.